# Is there a way to hide the Field List in Excel Power View?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Once I have created the Power View I want and close the Field List. Just leaving the actual View and Filter panel open. I save the whole workbook and close it.

When I reopen the workbook the field list panel is open again. I am not trying to hide it so no one will use it. I just don't want it there because it is not needed by the others that will view and use it. It will be a distraction, it takes up real estate and looks terrible when this is something I want someone to use as a "VIEW" of the information.

AS A SECONDARY QUESTION: I also just noticed that when I use the "Pop out" mechanism to make the View bigger, to see more data and remove the title. Then save, that also gets reset when I reopen the workbook. The title is back and the data has been compressed back to it's little viewable area. I have attached images of View normal with title and View with "pop out" activated, as you will see pop out View is much more useful (to me at least).
[The View as "Normal"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS6HB.png)
[The View in "Pop out" mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jUaS.png)

Answer (score 0):

`In Power Pivot you can either select to show hidden Fields or not. In Power View, there is no choice; if the item is marked (in Power Pivot) as hidden, you won’t be able to see it in Power View.` 
To hide a table, column, or field in Data View, right-click and select Hide from Client Tools.

For more Info [Click Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Power-Pivot-reporting-properties-Hiding-tables-columns-and-fields-from-Power-Pivot-and-Power-View-a9c1142f-7b27-4c60-8e31-67edf41fbf4b)